# Create a CBitmap from Resources ID

Tags: c++, mfc, resources, cbitmap

I need to fill a `CImageList` with a number of bitmaps which are stored in separate bmp files (rather than as a single bmp with numerous parts). I assume I need to create a `CBitmap` so I can call the `Add` method of `CImageList`. So how might one create a `CBitmap` object using only MFC Resource IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the method [CBitmap::LoadBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc99t364(VS.80).aspx).

You can either load the bitmap from the file or from resources.